# PySide2.QtWidgets recognized only in Anaconda prompt, but not when executing script

Tags: anaconda, pyside2

I installed PySide2 from conda-forge into an virtual environment named "Qt4Python".

It works if I directly type in the Anaconda prompt (in python):

```
import PySide2
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
```

However, if I write these 2 lines in a script file named test1.py, then also from Anaconda prompt call:

```
python test1.py
```

Then it produces:

> AttributeError: module 'PySide2' has no attribute 'QtWidgets'

What I was missing here ? Below is the package list of the environment.

```
(Qt4Python) C:\Users\XuanPhu\Desktop\ST_project>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\XuanPhu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Qt4Python:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
ca-certificates           2018.11.29           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.11.29            py37_1000    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1004    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.36            h7602738_1000    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.8             h9ce36c8_1005    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.32            heafd4d3_1002    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2p            hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pip                       18.1                  py37_1000    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                    py37_0
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0
pyside2                   5.6.0a1         py37h20f30f1_1003    conda-forge
python                    3.7.1             hc182675_1000    conda-forge
qt                        5.6.2                h2639256_8    conda-forge
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
shiboken2                 5.12.0                    <pip>
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.26.0            hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1004    conda-forge
```

Comment: thank @TDK, I was looking to format my question too :)

Comment: Also, If I used Python (the one in the Qt4Python env), I can do: "import PySide2", but can not "import PySide2.QtWidgets"

Answer (score 0):

There could be a *version mismatch* issue.
I can see you have `PySide2` from conda-forge which is really outdated `(5.6)`,
since `shiboken2` is using the latest available in pypi `(5.12.0)`,
additionally the `qt` you have there is not the same for the PySide2 version `(5.6.2)`.

At the moment there is **no** conda-forge `PySide2` package that uses the latest version, which is `5.12.0`.

I guess you can either contribute to the project and update the package, or move back and use `virtualenv`.